# Frobenius normalization implementation in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, normalization

I'm beginner in **tensorflow** and i want to apply [Frobenius normalization](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html) on a tensor but when i searched i didn't find any function related to it in tensorflow and i couldn't implement it using tensorflow ops, i can implement it with **numpy** operations, but how can i do this using tensorflow ops only ??

My implementation using **numpy** in python

```
def Frobenius_Norm(tensor):
   x = np.power(tensor,2)
   x = np.sum(x) 
   x = np.sqrt(x)
   return x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def frobenius_norm_tf(M):
    return tf.reduce_sum(M ** 2) ** 0.5
```